# Property of $\sup_{n\geq 1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ip^{-i}\right)$ for $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Let $p>1$ be a natural number and $(a_i)_{i\geq 1}$ a sequence of element of the interval $\{0,1\ldots,p-1\}$. Clearly $0\leq\sup_{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_ip^{-i}\leq 1$.

Let $\sup_{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_ip^{-i}=1$. I need to show that $a_i=p-1$ for all $i$. Suppose there exists $k\geq 1$ such that $a_k<p-1$. This implies that for all $n$ and for all $r\leq s$ such $r,s\in\{0,\ldots n-1\}$
$$\sum_{i=r}^sa_ip^{-i}<\frac{1}{p^{r-1}}-\frac{1}{p^s}.$$
I am not sure how I can use the above to find a contradiction. How can I proceed?

Comment: You write *"Suppose there exists $k\geq 1$ such that $a_k<p-1$."* That is great, but in your next sentence you don't mention your $k$ at all. You need to use this $a_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that $$1 \,>\, \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{p^i},$$
assuming that $a_k < p -1.$

The demonstration can be begun like this:

$$1 \,=\, \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p^i}\,>\,\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{p-1}{p^i}+\frac{a_k}{p^k}+\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p^i}.$$

**Appendix.**

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p^i}$ is a convergent series of positive terms; it converges to $1$. But given any series known to converge to a (finite) sum, we can always decompose it into two pieces, a finite beginning and an infinite tail. In other words, we apply the theorem

> If $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}c_j = L \in \mathbb{C},$ and if $1 < k < +\infty$, then
> $L = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}c_j + \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}c_j$. (It is implicit
> here that $\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}c_j$ necessariliy converges.)

Comment: Sorry I just realized that I'm not sure about one thing. Why are you allowed to write $\sum_{i=1}^\infty(p-1)p^{-i}=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(p-1)p^{-i}+(p-1)p^{-k}+\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty(p-1)p^{-i}$? The left hand side is equal to $1$. The right hand side is $1-p^{-k}+\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty(p-1)p^{-i}$. This would mean that $\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty(p-1)p^{-i}=p^{-k}$, which is not true.

Comment: You are correct: $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{p-1}{p^i} = 1 - \frac1{p^k}.\quad$ But I disagree with your next point, because I think $\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p^i} =\frac1{p^k}\quad$ is true.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. Thanks